# Google Analytics on Chrome store detail - Demographics, interests

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

Is there somehow how to enable the feature of Google Analytics that collects the interests, demographics data, such as age etc?

I have succesfully implement the new code in the Chrome extension but when I filter only the Webstore detail in the Google analytics report, I get no data about this.

Thank you very much for your reply.